# BigInteger modInverse Not Invertable Error

Tags: java, biginteger

I am trying to do e.modInverse(phi) variable but some values are invertible but some of the value says it is not invertible. I'm not sure why it gives me error that the number is not invertible (I checked the phi value but non of them were negatives)

```
    BigInteger n = new BigInteger("33");  //p = 3 * 11;
    BigInteger e = new BigInteger("4");
    BigInteger p = new BigInteger("3");
    BigInteger q = new BigInteger("11");
    BigInteger phi = (p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
    BigInteger d = e.modInverse(phi);
```

Comment: The Java doc for the modInverse method states that it will throw an Exception if "m ≤ 0, **or this BigInteger has no multiplicative inverse mod m (that is, this BigInteger is not relatively prime to m).**" - 4 and 20 are not relative prime to another.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: For RSA in particular (which is not the only place large modular integers are used) e must be invertible with respect to and thus coprime with _either_ Euler's totient phi(pq)=(p-1)x(q-1) or Carmichael's totient lambda(pq)=lcm(p-1,q-1) -- mathematically either works. [See steps 4 and 5, and the second paragraph after the list, in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Key_generation) or any other competently-written reference.